How to correctly use the values of injected objects as annotation values? I encountered a circular dependency issue when using SpEL
I have a Spring application where I need to use values from injected propertiesCancelAuthorizationLinkageListenerProperties properties in my @KafkaListener annotation.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CancelAuthorizationLinkageListener {
    private final CancelAuthorizationLinkageProcessor processor;
    private final CancelAuthorizationLinkageServiceInterface linkageService;
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, CancelAuthorizationLinkage> kafkaTemplate;
    private final CancelAuthorizationLinkageListenerProperties properties;

    public CancelAuthorizationLinkageListener(
            CancelAuthorizationLinkageProcessor processor,
            CancelAuthorizationLinkageServiceInterface linkageService,
            KafkaTemplate<String, CancelAuthorizationLinkage> kafkaTemplate,
            CancelAuthorizationLinkageListenerProperties properties) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.linkageService = linkageService;
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
        return new JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public BatchMessagingMessageConverter batchConverter() {
        return new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter());
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "#{cancelAuthorizationLinkageListener.properties.id}",
            topics = "#{cancelAuthorizationLinkageListener.properties.topic.cancelAuthLinkage}", autoStartup = "false",
            batch = "true",
            groupId = "cushion", concurrency = "2")
    @Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
    public void listen(List<Message<CancelAuthorizationLinkage>> resources) {
        for (Message<CancelAuthorizationLinkage> resource : resources) {
            try {
                CancelAuthorizationLinkageWriterResource cancelAuthorizationLinkageWriterResource =
                        processor.process(resource.getPayload());
                if (cancelAuthorizationLinkageWriterResource != null) {
                    linkageService.linkageAuthorization(
                            cancelAuthorizationLinkageWriterResource.getApiResource());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    handleFailure(resource);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.info("Error processing resource: {}", resource.getPayload().getAuthorizationId());
                    throw new RuntimeException("handleFailure failed: " + resource.getPayload().getAuthorizationId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The values for id, topics, and other properties are defined in a properties class:
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.kafka.listener.cancel-auth-linkage")
@Data
public class CancelAuthorizationLinkageListenerProperties {
    private String id;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Topic topic;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Header header;
    private int retryLimit;

    @Data
    public static class Topic {
        private String linkage;
        private String retry;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Header {
        private String nextRetryAttempt;
    }
}

However, I am encountering a circular dependency issue:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  cancelAuthorizationLinkageListener defined in file [/path/to/CancelAuthorizationLinkageListener.class]
└──<-──┘


I understand that using SpEL can cause such issues, but I am looking for a way to avoid this circular dependency while still being able to use injected values in my annotations.
How can I correctly inject these values into the @KafkaListener annotation without causing circular dependencies?
